# Use Google Sheet Authentication for application, not for end user

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use Google Sheet in my application. This google sheet is not related to end user but will be under my own account. As per some tutorial on [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) I have created project on developer console but during OAuth 2.0 authentication, Google display login dialog to end user. As said before, this sheet is not related to end user so how can I fix my own Google credentials in code so that it just work with sheet, without asking user for his credentials?

Here is my code snippet

```
            var clientSecret = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets() { ClientId = "*******.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret = "*******" };
            var credential = Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecret,
                Scopes,
                "myemail@google.com",
                System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;
            var service = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks there are no such ways yet. So finally I decided to use local database and then export content to Excel using ClosedXML library.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to publish the article publicly?

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en

You can use this method, then embed the sheet in an iframe on your site

Comment: Dear Vinnie, 
I don't want to display sheet to user. My application flow is like this:
User enter some URL in my web application, application crawl the page and extract some required information and will store in Google Sheet. This sheet won't be displayed in page to user. 
Admin can only view sheet online with all data stored. So you can say that Google Sheet will act like database. 
I don't think publish sheet serve the required purpose or can I update sheet programmatically in code behind?

Comment: You might try https://sheetsu.com orthodox node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet